# I'm trying to add ArrayList twice(with different content) to 2-D ArrayList, but 2-D ArrayList got same content?

Tags: java

Below is my java code, but eventually I'm going to create 2-D ArrayList in for-loop, that's why I test it first to use same ArrayList(sList).

```
package fc;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AppendList03 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> wList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> sList = new ArrayList<String>();
        sList.add("1");
        sList.add("2");     
        System.out.println(sList); 
        
        wList.add(sList);
        System.out.println(wList);
        
        sList.clear();
        sList.add("3");
        wList.add(sList);
        System.out.println(wList);
        
    }

}
```

Comment: This is the result I got!

Comment: [1, 2]
[[1, 2]]
[[3], [3]]

Comment: You've added an object to the wList ArrayList, and then *modify* the same object added. Your result is not surprising in this light. If you want a new ArrayList,  you must first create a ***new*** ArrayList. So not, `sList.clear();` but rather `sList = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: It works, Thanks a lot! Below is my new code.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {  
  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> wList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
  ArrayList<String> sList;
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
   sList = new ArrayList<String>();
   sList.add(String.valueOf(i));     
   wList.add(sList); 
  }
  System.out.println(wList);
 }

Comment: [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]]